# Within React, why am I not able to use nested arrow functions... Altough normal functions seem to work?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

The following doesn't work.

```
generateFakeAnswer = () => {
    getRealAnswer = (state) => {
      return state.valueOne + state.valueTwo + state.valueThree;
    }

    this.setState({
      fakeAnswer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + getRealAnswer(this.state)
    })
  }
```

But the following does work.

```
generateFakeAnswer = () => {
    function getRealAnswer(state) {
      return state.valueOne + state.valueTwo + state.valueThree;
    }

    this.setState({
      fakeAnswer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + getRealAnswer(this.state)
    })
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already don't have `let getRealAnswer` You should make a new const inside your `function`.

> Strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work" (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript). Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead throw an error in strict mode:

```
                       // Assuming no global variable mistypeVariable exists
mistypeVariable = 17;  // this line throws a ReferenceError due to the
                       // misspelling of variable
```

So you function should be like this:

```
generateFakeAnswer = () => {
    const getRealAnswer = (state) => {
      return state.valueOne + state.valueTwo + state.valueThree;
    }

    this.setState({
      fakeAnswer: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + getRealAnswer(this.state)
    })
}
```

Comment: Wow! I wasn't expecting that... Would you kindly explain the reasoning? Why is `const` or `let` compulsory here?

Comment: Because you cannot use `a="a"` this means you already have `let a` and inside the modular project, this doesn't allow.

Comment: I apologise, but I don't understand... `getRealAnswer="getRealAnswer"`? How am I doing that?

Comment: yes, you did! try this, before your component adds this `let getRealAnswer` and see what happened.

Comment: @Grateful `getRealAnswer = (state) => {...}`  tries to assign the function to a pre-existent variable `getRealAnswer` (and throws if there isn't any (in strict mode, at least)), while `const getRealAnswer = (state) => {...}` creates a new one.

Comment: @Grateful since getRealAnswer is a function which u are calling, while using keyword function , the compiler got to know its a function, but while using arrow function your are assigning that function definition to a variable which by default in every language must have its data type.

Comment: @Grateful: Maybe you are coming from [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields)? While looking similar, those are actually creating properties on an object, and the context is totally different. The meaning of syntax is context dependent. Variables are always declared with `var`,`let` or `const` (and `class` and `function` if you want to be pedantic).